# Error reading a property list

Tags: objective-c, arrays, properties

I have a property list that has a dictionary at the root and 21 arrays as rows,ordered by their corresponding key.
Each key has array (value) of 8 strings. 
Something like this:

> ```
>   Root                     Dictionary       (21 items)
>   "#14"                     Array           (8 items)   
>   "#12"                     Array           (8 items)
>     Item 0                  String           0.164
>     Item 1                  String           0.123
>     item 2                  String           0.211
> ```

.... so on

in my implementation file, I have:

> `- (void)loadTable9NECWithBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
>      {
>
> ```
>    bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle] ;
>     if (bundle != nil)
>     {
>   /* Read the cable table data from the disk in a dictionary of arrays. Each array contains >       only one cable size data. */
>       NSString *CableData = [bundle pathForResource:@"Table9-NEC" ofType:@"plist"];
>        NSDictionary *tableDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:CableData];
>        NSString *datos = nil;
>        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [tableDict keyEnumerator];
>        id key;
>        while ((key = [enumerator nextObject]))
>        {
>        oneCableSizeDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[tableDict >     valueForKey:key] ,nil];
>        NSLog(@"key is %@ ", key);
>           datos = [oneCableSizeDataArray objectAtIndex: 0 ];
>            NSLog(@"value is %@ ", datos);
>
>       }
> ```

The console show clearly that I could iterate trough all keys correctly, however the array oneCableSizeDataArray get the value as a single string, not a 8 string as in the plist file representation., it means [oneCableSizeDataArray count] returns 1. (single object).

I can not figure out why this is happening.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not on the Mac I'm doing iOS development on right now, but from what I remember you don't want to use `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile`, you want to use [`propertyListWithData:options:format:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nspropertylistserialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as otherwise it won't load the nested properties correctly. The result of that message can be assigned to an `NSDictionary` object and accessed as you would normally. (Speaking of that, the more recent versions of Xcode support more succinct indexing and key access, such as `oneCableSizeDataArray[0]` and `tableDict["#14"]`.)

Comment: actually the property list is created manually in Xcode, it is basically immutable, no user accessible and the application is for iOS. I will try to research on what you mention and report any good news.

Comment: UPDATE:I just change the initialization of the oneCableSizeDataArray from oneCableSizeDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[tableDict valueForKey:key] ,nil]; to initWithArray... In this case the array is properly configured. And yes, oneCableSIzeDataArray[0] works pretty good. Thanks JAB for that.

Comment: @user1544073 You don't even need `initWithArray`, `datos = [[tableDict valueForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];` (or `datos = tableDict[key][0];` in more recent versions of Xcode) will work just fine. In fact, I would suggest that method as it reduces unnecessary code and memory usage, unless you need the ability to mutate the elements retrieved from the property list (though not necessarily mutate the property list itself).

Comment: Also note that using fast enumeration is preferred (`for (id key in dict)`) rather than using an external iterator. You could also try enumerating with blocks (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:), though that might be a bit trickier to get a grasp on (and I'm not sure if it would be any more efficient than fast enumeration).

Comment: talking about enumeration, do you know any way to enumerate keys and values in NSUserDefaults.?

Comment: @user1544073 It appears [`[NSUserDefaults dictionaryRepresentation]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/dictionaryRepresentation) may be useful for that.